# ICNET Fast Segmentation on android using TFLite

Tags: android, tensorflow-lite

I am trying to use the ICNET for segmentation on the Android using TFLite.More information on ICNET here [here](https://modeldepot.io/oandrienko/icnet-for-fast-segmentation). I don't know TFLite much and resource are less can anyone help me in code conversion.

My Version of TFLite is

```
compile 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:0.0.0-nightly'
```

Answer (score 0):

Why specifically ICNET?? Is there any particular need? We are also looking into integrating segmentation model on android devices using TFLite. If you need, check out tflite_convert function in Tensorflow.